# What tools could help you plan a trip to attend concerts of major European symphonies?

Tags: planning, events, music, travel-tools

I am curious if there exists a travel planning tool which can help organize a trip around concerts of the major European symphonies.

As an example, let's say I really want to see the Berlin Philharmonic play one of my favorite works. How could I figure out which weekend(s) I should plan on going to Berlin? Or maybe I just care about a particular piece, and want to see who is playing it in the near future.

Ideally it should be easy to figure out:

- Who is playing?
- What are they playing?
- What hall are they playing in?
- How much (roughly) are tickets?

(Of course, going to each individual orchestra's page is not an attractive option.)

Comment: You could use https://www.timeout.com/berlin/en/music/berlin-opera-houses-concert-halls-theatres - but for some reason they have neither schedules nor ticketing info apparent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the exception of ticket prices, [BachTrack](https://bachtrack.com/) does most of what you want.  One can search by city, by hall, by orchestra, by composer, or by work (or any combination thereof), and find performances for the next year.  The listings aren't complete—it focuses on major orchestras in major cities—but that's probably what you would be interested in for travel purposes.

[image]